# How to set Content-Length when object is passed as response

Tags: asp.net, json, iis-7

I have JSON object in my ASP.Net app which I pass to response using code

```
context.Response.Write(jsonObject)
```

The problem is that I need to set the Content-Length header to indicate response size and I do not know how to count it. How do I get filesize of Object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the JSON object is a string, something like

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", jsonObject.Length);
```

should work.

Comment: Please change this response. It should be length IN BYTES not count of characters. E.g. "Hi ☺" is 4 characters, byt of byte length 6.

Answer (score 1):

usually you do like this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", yourLength);
```